# How do I show a realtionship on an instance of an object in Sparx Enterprise Architect?

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I am trying to visually show a relationship on an instance of an object in enterprise architect.
I have a requirement “A” and an instance of a class B, “:B”. Between the two objects I have created a dependency relationship. I would like this relationship to be visible by adding the class name to the instance (for example in the lower right corner) everywhere when the instance is used. 
This would mean that in any diagram where ”:B” is used it would clearly seen that “:B” has a relationship to ”A”, even if “A” is not present in the diagram.
Is this possible? I have tried shapescripts without success.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the answer is "not out of the box," because a shape script for an element cannot access the element's connectors. (A shape script for a connector, by contrast, can access certain properties of its source and target elements.) However, there are two alternatives.

**Alternative 1**

If you represent the requirements not as individual Requirement elements but as internal requirements (accessed in the Requirements tab of the object's properties dialog), you can display them in diagrams by selecting Requirements in the Elements tab of the diagram's properties dialog (makes the setting diagram-wide), or by selecting Responsibilities in the object's Feature and Compartment Visibility dialog (selects it for that element only).

Please note that with the latter option you can also select display of Inherited Responsibilities, which in your case would show, in the object `:B`, any requirements on the class `B`.

The disadvantage is that this only works for internal requirements. EA allows you to make internal requirements external, that is, to create proper Requirement elements from the list entries in the Requirements tab, but while this does not remove the externalized requirements from that list, it does stop them from being displayed in diagrams in the above manner.

**Alternative 2**

Shape scripts offer a get-out-of-jail-free card in the form of the `addin` property. This allows your shape script to call a function in an Add-In and display the results. So you could write an Add-In with a function which returns the names of all connected Requirement elements and call that. I've used this to display requirements in a similar manner to what you're describing, but that was for a client so I can't post any of that code here.

The disadvantage with the Add-In approach is that anyone who looks at the model needs to have the Add-In installed or the requirements won't show up. But the shape script won't go crazy and crash (it'll just quietly skip any calls to Add-Ins it can't find), and you'll still be able to find the requirements the old-fashioned way by following the links in the properties dialog, or the Traceability View, or the Element Browser.

Which is the better alternative? Well, it depends... I personally prefer modelling requirements as proper, separate elements (possibly starting out as internal requirements, which are then externalized) because it gives you more flexibility. But you should only go the Add-In route if you have some control over the clients, that is, if you can make sure all modellers have the Add-In installed.

Comment: We have tried Alternative1, but it does not seem to fill our needs. This because we can't seem to trace the requirement A to several different instances of objects :B, :C etc.
Regarding Alternative2 we will try it. For us it seems the correct way to go. How do you call an Addin from the shape script?